Error, core reset when encoding FFMPEG
ffmpeg -i {file} -cpu-used 8 -movflags +faststart -map_metadata -1 \
        -c:v libaom-av1 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
        -c:a libopus -b:a 128k \
        -map 0:a:0 \
        -map 0:v:0 -filter:v:0 scale=-2:144,fps=25,setdar=16/9  -g:v:0 250 -minrate:v:0 35k   -b:v:0 60k    -maxrate:v:0 118k \
        -map 0:v:0 -filter:v:1 scale=-2:240,fps=25,setdar=16/9  -g:v:1 250 -minrate:v:1 75k   -b:v:1 150k   -maxrate:v:1 218k \
        -pass 1 -f null /dev/null && \
        ffmpeg -i {file} -cpu-used 8 -movflags +faststart -map_metadata -1 \
        -c:v libaom-av1 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
        -c:a libopus -b:a 128k \
        -map 0:a:0 \
        -map 0:v:0 -filter:v:0 scale=-2:144,fps=25,setdar=16/9  -g:v:0 250 -minrate:v:0 35k   -b:v:0 60k    -maxrate:v:0 118k \
        -map 0:v:0 -filter:v:1 scale=-2:240,fps=25,setdar=16/9  -g:v:1 250 -minrate:v:1 75k   -b:v:1 150k   -maxrate:v:1 218k \
        -init_seg_name "init-\\$RepresentationID\\$.\\$ext\\$"\
        -media_seg_name "sg-\\$RepresentationID\\$-\\$Number%05d\\$.\\$ext\\$" \
        -dash_segment_type auto \
        -use_template 1 -use_timeline 1 -seg_duration 9 \
        -adaptation_sets "id=0, streams=v id=0, streams=a" \
        -pass 2 -f dash /manifest.mpd

I've been sitting here for days, not understanding what the error is...
It starts coding in a random place, at 30%, at 50% of progress. It gives the following error...
ffmpeg: ./av1/encoder/bitstream.c:281: write_motion_mode: Assertion `mbmi->motion_mode <= last_motion_mode_allowed' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

What is this kernel dump?
While I was trying to figure it out, I rewrote my script 10 times, downloaded it, but the problem was not solved....
